# Best way to make a part of a Grid invisible

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to bind the visibility of a part of a Grid to a Property in the ViewModel. I came up with a solution, where I put another Grid inside the Grid that contains the Controls that should be collapsed. The nasty part of this is, that there are redundant ColumnDefinitions:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        ...
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="110"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="140"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="140"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    ...
    <Grid Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="100" Visibility="{Binding VisibilityProperty}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            ... (some more rows)
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="110"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="140"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="140"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        ...
    </Grid>
```

Another solution that came to my mind was binding the Visibility of each Control, resulting in much more Bindings than in the above shown way.

My question is: Is there any better way to hide a part of a Grid? I'm especially curious if it is possible to reuse the ColumnDefinitions of the parent Grid.

Comment: Have you used WrapPanel?

Comment: I used it occassionally, but I don't know how I should use it in this case

Comment: You could set up your Grid Structure as a ContentControl template with a ContentPresenter to plop in your objects with their respectively declared Grid.Row, Grid.Column declarations on each that would allow you to reuse the grid structure, but I'm not sure if that's ideal just to re-use once.

Comment: You could try to use a DataGrid and DataGridRows. Not sure if that helps, but maybe you can make it work that way.

Comment: @TimPohlmann do you mean I could bind the Visibility of the DataGridRows instead of creating the child grid?

Comment: @Breeze yes exactly. Use a DataGrid instead of a Grid. Then use DataGridRows and bind their Visibility. If you want to hide a lot of rows that's a bunch of Bindings anyway, so I'm not sure if this is the perfect solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `WrapPanel` instead of nested `Grid`. You can wrap controls from right to left by setting the `FlowDirection` property to
`RightToLeft` and set `Visibility` property to what you want. For example:

```
<Window x:Class="SOWpfApplication.MainWindow"
    <!--The code is omitted for the brevity.-->
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button Click="Button_Click" Margin="5" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">Hide the WrapPanel</Button>

    <WrapPanel Name="wrapPanel" Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
        <TextBox Text="Hello, dude!" Margin="5"/>
        <Button Content="I am the Button!" Margin="0,5,0,5"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Hey, I am textBlock!"/>
    </WrapPanel>       

</Grid>
</Window>
```

To hide your `WrapPanel` you can use `Visibility` property as shown here:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if(wrapPanel.Visibility!= System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden)
     wrapPanel.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
   else
     wrapPanel.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Comment: But I also have RowDefinitions, WrapPanel won't be able to handle that, will it? (I now added it more obvious to the question)

Comment: I don't think you got what the Grid(s) look like (maybe I didn't describe it good enough, or it's my fault not completely understanding your answer). There are not only Rows in the parent Grid but also in the child Grid. Putting the Controls of the child Grid inside a WrapPanel would as far as I know align all Controls as close to each other as possible and therefore messing up the structure of several rows

Comment: yes, the Controls have to stay in the same alignment and order

Comment: so as I far I know there is Grid where you can tune your order manually. Try WrapPanel. Other layouts controls would order controls automatically as far I know. See this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514628(v=vs.90).aspx  or http://www.wpftutorial.net/LayoutProperties.html

Comment: the links confirm that I need a Grid. The Grid example is exactly what I need (and have). I just hope to find a better way to hide a part of it.